# Fetching of mail status by using Sendgrid API

Tags: java, sendgrid

I want to fetch the sent mail status by using Sendgrid API. While I am trying to call it through a java code, the code is running properly but I am getting a 403- Access Forbidden error.

What is the reason and the solution for it? The API key has full permission. I have attached two image links(code and output) below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot of your code it looks like you are trying to get your API key by calling `System.getenv("YOUR_ACTUAL_API_KEY")`.

When calling on `System.getenv` you should pass the name of an environment variable in which you have stored your API key. So, you should store your environment variable in a variable called something like `SENDGRID_API_KEY` and then retrieve it in your program like:

```java
System.getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY")
```

You can read more about [working with environment variables in Java](https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-java) and [how to set environment variables](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html).

Comment: I am passing the actual API key by calling the getenv() method. The blue erased line in the code is the actual Sendgrid API key.

Comment: That's what I mean. When you call `getenv()` it uses the string you pass to it to look up the environment variable by name and return it. You are passing it the actual API key, not the environment variable. The actual API key should not appear in your code. You should set the API key as an environment variable with a name like "SENDGRID_API_KEY" and then call `getenv()` with that name.

Comment: I just tried that by putting the Sendgrid API key in a user env variable and passing the name"SENDGRID_API_KEY" in the parameter of the getenv() method. but same issue, 403-access forbidden.

Comment: Are you able to log out the API key within the program to make sure it has been loaded properly?

Comment: I have just restarted my eclipse, then again executed the code. now I am getting 500-internal server exception error.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Few minutes before i again executed the code and got 404- resource not found error. I got two different errors in last two executions. But I did not change anything in the code.

Comment: Your URL should be `/v3/stats`. That would explain the 404.

Comment: Is it required to send the username of that particular Sendgrid account through the header?

Comment: Are you trying to get the stats for a subuser?

Comment: No. As I don't have any subuser in this account.

Comment: Then you don’t need to send a username.

Comment: Okay. Is there any endpoint to get the individual mail status instead of the global mail status?

Comment: There isn’t, it’s far more efficient to receive events about your emails by listening to the [Event webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook).

Comment: The code was executed some minutes before and got the output. But for that, I had to pass the username in the header.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking any more, your comments have gone off track regarding your original question. If this question is solved, please mark it so. If you have more questions, please start a new question with the code you are referring to. Thanks!

Comment: The 403 error that was coming earlier, is not coming now and the code got executed.

Comment: So, success then?

Comment: Yes. I marked your answer as "accepted". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you! Hope the rest of your app goes well.